Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.spree_users' with unique index 'email_idx_unique'
We have received an error in Sentry:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
TinyTds::Error: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.spree_users' with unique index 'email_idx_unique'. The duplicate key value is (x.kl@xl.com). (ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)
TinyTds::Error
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.spree_users' with unique index 'email_idx_unique'. The duplicate key value is (x.kl@xl.com).

Code:
def create_full_registration
  @user = Spree::User.new(user_params)
  @user.user_registrations.build(site: site, status: "pending")
  if @user.save
    @form_submission = FormSubmission.new(
      form_type: "registration",
      form_data: form_data_params,
      status: "pending",
      user: @user
    )
    unless @form_submission.save
      render_errors(@form_submission.errors)
    end
  else
    render_errors(@user.errors)
  end
end

Schema:
create_table "spree_users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "encrypted_password", limit: 128
  t.string "password_salt", limit: 128
  t.string "email"
  t.string "remember_token"
  ...
  t.index ["deleted_at"], name: "index_spree_users_on_deleted_at"
  t.index ["email"], name: "email_idx_unique", unique: true
end

My question is, as everything is in place, why would it happen like this? We also have client validations, which means the user must see that the email already exists on UI. And what could be the potential fix? An exception handling only?
We want it to appear again with a potential fix.

This is a race condition, this can happen when the user double taps the submit button, or the client app sends two requests at about the same time. The two server processes have no idea about the other and the first one in wins. Best to handle the exception. The unique validation is not terribly useful for this reason.

Got that, thanks for the explanation.
So you mean add to exceptions at rails side?

I am using nextjs so that means for some reason 2 requests get fired at the same time?

Yes and yes —  handle the exceptions at the rails level
